# Anchor point seems incorrect for Chemfig package

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, chemfig

I'm trying to use chemfig to draw a basic schematic for enzymatic browning and have encountered a problem. In the bottom reaction (bottom right to bottom left) quinone is formed by the enzyme (denoted by the bracket underneath). The anchor for the curved arrow, however, seems to be incorrectly placed and try as I might I have not been able to solve the problem. I've tried flipping it every which way to no avail. Any tips?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{2em}
\setbondoffset{0.5pt}
\setarrowdefault{,1.5,}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
\chemup.\chemfig{N-[:30]Cu-[:150]N}\qquad\chemfig{N-[:150]Cu-[:30]N}\chemdown]
\arrow{-U>[*{0.0}{\chemfig{O_2}, \chemfig{H_2O}}]}[90,2]
\chemup.\chemfig{N-[:30]Cu(-[:150]N)(-[:90,,,2,]H_2O)-[:30]O-O-[:-30]Cu(-[:90]OH_2)(-[:30]N)-[:-30]N}\chemdown]
\arrow{-U>[\chemfig{**6([,0.5]----(-OH)--)}][\chemfig{H_2O}]}[0]
\chemup.\chemfig{N-[:30]Cu(-[:150]N)(-[:90]O-[:30]**6([,0.5]------))-[:30]O-O-[:-30]Cu(-[:90]OH_2)(-[:30]N)-[:-30]N}\chemdown]
\arrow{-U>[*{0.180}2\chemfig{H^+}][*{0.180}\chemfig{H_2O}]}[-90]
\chemup.\chemfig{N-[:30]Cu(-[:150]N)-[:30]O-[:90]**6([:60,0.5]-(-[:-90,1]O-[:-30,1]Cu(-[:30,1]N)-[:-30,1]N)-----)}\chemdown]
\arrow{-U>[][*{0.north}\chemfig{*6([:-30,0.5]-(=[:-120]O)-(=[:-60]O)-=-=)}]}[180,1.85]
\schemestop
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not see that when I compile your MWE. The anchor is at its normal place (i.e. *above* the ring and *not* inside it). Pershaps your latex distribution needs an update?

[image]

Comment: I actually just reinstalled MiKTeX 2.9.4813 (for this and unrelated reasons) and I'm still getting the same result. I'm using TeXstudio and compiling with XeLaTeX, if either of those could be contributing factors.

Comment: I use linux+texlive13 and the result remains the same with xelatex. I'm afraid I can't help you because I do not have windows and I never runned miktex.

Comment: Thanks anyways. I'll continue fiddling with it and see if I can get any result.